# Balls Picking Question

Tags: probability

Let's say we play balls picking game. There are 100 balls and 12 different colours of ball. They are all put in a box. The rule is once a ball is picked, that colour of balls in the box will be removed at the same time. I want to know what is the probabilty of a particular colour, e.g. yellow, being picked in 3 chances given the condition I don't know what kind of colour was picked until yellow has been picked. The number of balls of different colours is known before the game started. Is there any general formulas for calculating the probability?

My thought is:
P(Ball) = Number of Ball / 100

P(Yellow_Ball) + (1-(P(Yellow_Ball)) * P(Yellow_Ball)/(1 - the probability of balls being picked in the first shot)) + .......

And I am stucked coz I don't know how to generalize the  proba of the first picked ball and also the second one.

Comment: The proba to pick yellow at 1st try is nbYellow/NbTotal , ok. For try n°2 it is more complex, you need to substract a color, so you need to know how are distributed the other colors. If other colors are 8+8+8+8+...+9+9, or 1+1+1+2+2+...+60, the result will be totally different. You can illustrate your reflexion, with a decision-tree  (with only 5 colors for example, to have something not to big). You should find the logic by yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Let there be $N_i$ balls of colour $i$ for each $i = 1, \ldots, 12$. So $N_1 + \cdots + N_{12} = 100$. Now let $C_1, C_2, C_3$ be the random variables denoting the colour of the first, second and third ball picked. Then

\begin{align*}
\Pr[C_3 = i] &= \sum_{j,k} \Pr[C_3 = i \mid C_2 = j, C_1 = k] \Pr[C_2 = j \mid C_1 = k] \Pr[C_1 = k]\\
&= \sum_{j,k} \frac{N_i}{100 - N_j - N_k}\cdot\frac{N_j}{100 - N_k}\cdot\frac{N_k}{100}
\end{align*}
Where the summation is over all $j, k \in \{1,\ldots, 12\}\setminus \{i\}$ such that $j \ne k$.